Non-WWW to WWW Redirect Not Working in .htaccess for HTTPS React App on Apache with Cloudflare – "Too Many Redirects" Error
I'm trying to configure my React app hosted on an Apache server to ensure that all versions of my domain (http://example.com, https://example.com, http://www.example.com, and https://www.example.com) redirect to the website. However, I keep running into a "too many redirects" error when accessing https://example.com, rest are working fine
Note: I'm using example.com here in place of the actual URL due to company policies.
My app uses React Router for client-side routing, and I'm using Cloudflare for DNS and SSL. Here’s what I’ve done so far:

DNS and SSL Settings:


Both example.com and www.example.com point to the correct IP address.
My SSL certificate covers with and without www in URL
In Cloudflare, SSL is set to Full (not Flexible), and I've also tried Full (Strict).


Current .htaccess Configuration:

# Enable Rewrite Engine
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Non-WWW to WWW with HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

# Ensure HTTPS for WWW
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example.com\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

# Support for Client-Side Routing in React
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]

# Set Default Directory Index
DirectoryIndex index.html

# Custom Error Pages
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
ErrorDocument 500 /500.html


Troubleshooting Steps:

Cleared Browser Cache and Purged Cloudflare Cache.
Tested different SSL settings in Cloudflare ("Full" and "Full (Strict)").
Tried using Cloudflare’s Page Rule with "Always Use HTTPS" for example.com/ (no success).

Questions:

Is there anything wrong with my .htaccess configuration that could be causing this redirect loop?
Could Cloudflare’s SSL or caching settings be interfering with the .htaccess rules, and if so, how can I adjust them to avoid the conflict?
Are there alternative ways to enforce the non-www to www redirection without causing a loop?

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Can you see in your browser dev tools, what those redirects are? Is it https://example.com -> https://example.com -> https://example.com multiple times in direct succession; or is it https://example.com -> something else -> https://example.com -> something else?

At least the HTTP to HTTPS redirect you should be able to configure directly on CloudFlare's end, that's probably preferable to begin with. https://developers.cloudflare.com/ssl/edge-certificates/additional-options/always-use-https/

And the non-WWW to WWW could be done there as well, by setting up a page rule.

it is being directed to https://example.com again and again when accessing the website with https://example.com where as when accessing website with other mentioned pattern the request goes to www.example.com

I had the same issue getting the Too many redirects error. My setup a bit different - React App running on Azure Static Apps and I use CNAME records with a URL, not the IP address, but I believe the core issue might be the same. It had nothing to do with .htaccess or React but with Cloudflare configuration. The final step that resolved it for me setting SSL/TLS encryption to full strict. Below are the settings that I've applied:

The CNAME record named example.com points to the URL where the app is deployed on Azure.
CNAME record named www pointing to example.com
SSL/TLS settings > Configure > Full (Strict)
Rules > Redirect Rules > Create Rule > click Redirect from HTTP to HTTPS - Create Rule. Set Request URL to http://* and Target URL to https://${1}

I also think that it's better to handle the redirection part on Cloudflare rather that on .htaccess
